# An example of a non-Hausdorff space X, and a compact subset, which is not relatively compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am trying to find an example of a non-Hausdorff space $X$ and a subset $A$ of $X$, which is compact, but not relatively compact, i.e. the closure $\overline{A}$ of $A$ is not compact. 
I thought I had found an example, namely $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the cofinite topology (since I know that infinite topological spaces with the cofinite topology is not Hausdorff), and $\mathbb{N}$ as a subset. But then I have that the closure of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, which I can see is compact with the cofinite topology, which was not what I was looking for.
Now I'm stuck, so is there anyone that can give me a hint of a non-Hausdorff space and (maybe) a compact subset? I feel there must be some simpler examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $X=\mathbb{N}$ with the topology with base $A=\{\{0,n\}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$. Then $\{0\}$ is compact and its closure is $X$. The covering $A$, of $X$, has no finite sub-covering.

Comment: How should $\{\{0,n\}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be understood?

Comment: @Sara Just the set $\{\{0,n\}:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example: let $X$ be an infinite set and $p \in X$.

Define $\mathcal{T}_p = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{A \subseteq X\mid p \in A\}$, the so-called included point point topology.

Then $A=\{p\}$ is compact (even finite), and $\overline{A}=X$ and $X$ is not compact, as witnessed by the (infinite) open cover $\{\{x,p\}: x \in X, x \neq p\}$, which has no proper subcover at all.

$X$ is $T_0$, but no higher.

Comment: Thank you for the example, it makes a lot of sense. But we haven't been introduced to this topology in my class, so I think I have to show that $\mathcal{T}_p$ is a topology and $X$ is non-Hausdroff. I have no trouble showing it is a topology, but I don't know if my idea about why it is non-Hausdorff is wrong: you wrote it is $T_0$, my idea is that the neighborhoods of the to distinct points $x$ and $y$, has a non-empty intersection? Because $p$ must be in their intersection?

Comment: @compaq.43 yes, there are no disjoint nonempty open sets as they all contain $p$. That it’s a topoooyis easy to prove.