# Let X be Hausdorff. If $A\subseteq X$ is compact then $\overline{A}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am doing this exercise where we let X be a topological Hausdorff space. I need to show that if $A\subseteq X$ is compact then the closure $\overline{A}$ is compact as well. Furthermore I have to find an example of a non-Hausdorff space X and a subset A that is compact but where $\overline{A}$ is not compact.

I am thinking since A is a compact subspace of a Hausdorff space X, then A is closed. Furthermore we have that $A\subseteq \overline{A}$. So $\overline{A}$ may be compact, because if it is not, the A cannot be compact since we have that every closed subspace of a compact space is compact. Then we'll have a contradiction, because we assumed that A is compact. Can I do it this way, or am I doing something wrong? Furthermore I am a little confused about which example to use.

Comment: If $A$ is closed, what is its closure?

Comment: Not sure what is the point of the exercise. If $A$ is closed then $A=\overline{A}$...

Comment: So that's what may be the point of the exercise

Comment: See a non-Hausdorff with a compact subspace which closure is non-compact [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158963/an-example-of-a-non-hausdorff-space-x-and-a-compact-subset-which-is-not-relati#comment8613039_4158963)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is put in a strange way.

If $X$ is Hausdorff, and $A$ is compact then $A$ is closed so $A = \overline{A}$. So then there is nothing to prove, really.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4159096/4280) I give an example of a non-Hausdorff space with compact $A$ where $A$ is not closed and we even have that $\overline{A}$ is *not* compact.